# Regex find list values within multiple multi-line strings python

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm looking for some help searching for list criteria within a string with multiple lines but similar patterns. Each subquery has `as (` and  `),`. so `as space (` and `space ),` pattern. I'd like to search the sub criteria within each pattern and produce an output.

```
sub = ['apple.apple','event.pear','strawberry']
```

and a multiple, multi-line strings like this -

```
qry = 

with

qry_1 as ( select some code, var as var_1 from apple where code.. and code..
),
qry_2 as ( select some from_code some code, where var as var_2 from pear where code.. and code..
),
qry_3 as ( select some from_code some from strawberry join some code, from apple where var as var_3, )
)
```

I'd like to be able to search the sub list within these queries and identify where they exist. I have something like this, but unsure how to make it work.

```
find_sub = [re.findall(sub, i)
     for i in re.findall(search separate text, qry)]
# create dictionary output
dict_sub = dict([k,dict_sub[k]) for k in sub])
dict_sub
```

where it looks like -

```
'apple.apple' : ['qry_1','qry_3']
'event.pear' : ['qry_2']
'strawberry' : ['qry_3']
```

I think I'm close and had some help on this, but am stuck on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the subquery name and associated fields, and then build the desired dictionary:

```
import re, collections
qry = '\nwith\n\nqry_1 as ( select some code, var as var_1 from apple where code.. and code..\n),\nqry_2 as ( select some code, where var as var_2 from pear where code.. and code..\n),\nqry_3 as ( select some code from strawberry join some code, from apple where var as var_3, )\n)\n'
d, d1 = collections.defaultdict(list), {}
for i in re.split('(?<=\),)\n', qry):
    a, *_b = re.findall('\w+(?=\sas\s\()|(?<=from\s)\w+', i)
    b = [i for i in _b if i in sub]
    for k in b:
       d[k].append(a)
    d1[a] = b

print(dict(d))
print(dict(d1))
```

Output:

```
{'apple': ['qry_1', 'qry_3'], 'pear': ['qry_2'], 'strawberry': ['qry_3']}
{'qry_1': ['apple'], 'qry_2': ['pear'], 'qry_3': ['strawberry', 'apple']}
```

---

**Edit**: Due to the complexity of your queries, I suggest using the [`sqlparse`](https://sqlparse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package. `sqlparse` will create a navigatable structure that can be traversed to grab the desired info.

First, install `sqlparse`:

```
pip3 install sqlparse
```

Then, parse and traverse the query. The function `get_fields` searches for identifiers that come after `from` or `join` keywords. These identifiers can be table names or queries. The parameter `all_identifiers` will grab any identifier statement, regardless of whether or not it proceeds a `from` or `join`. In the context of your parsing problem, setting this parameter to `True` will search for the fields chosen by the `select` block, as well as identifiers after `from` or `join`:

```
import sqlparse
from sqlparse import tokens as T
sub = ['apple.apple','event.pear','strawberry']
qry = """
with qry_1 as (
   select a.* from apple.apple a
),
with qry_2 as (
   select a.* from apple a join strawberry s on a.id = s.id
),
with qry_3 as (
   select a.* from (select k.* from event.pear p) l join apple.apple a on l.id = a.id join (select x.* s from strawberry s where s.m = (select max(l) from ignore_field where l.id = s.id)) k3 on k3 = a.id
)
"""
def get_fields(block, all_identifiers = False):
   seen_id = all_identifiers
   for i in getattr(block, 'tokens', []):
      if i.ttype == T.Keyword and i.value.lower() in {'from', 'join'}:
         seen_id = True
      if seen_id and isinstance(i, sqlparse.sql.Identifier):
         yield i.get_alias()
         if any(isinstance(k, sqlparse.sql.Parenthesis) for k in getattr(i, 'tokens', [])):
            yield from get_fields(i, all_identifiers = seen_id)
         else:
            yield from re.findall('^[\w+\.]+|\w+', str(i))
      elif seen_id:
          yield from get_fields(i, all_identifiers = seen_id)

p = sqlparse.parse(qry)
k = {i.tokens[0].value:list(get_fields(i.tokens[-1])) for j in p for i in j.tokens if isinstance(i, sqlparse.sql.Identifier)}
d1, d2 = collections.defaultdict(list), {}
for a, _b in k.items():
    for i in (b:=[j for j in _b if j in sub]):
       d1[i].append(a)
    d2[a] = b

print(dict(d1))
print(dict(d2))
```

Output:

```
{'apple.apple': ['qry_1', 'qry_3'], 'strawberry': ['qry_2', 'qry_3'], 'event.pear': ['qry_3']}
{'qry_1': ['apple.apple'], 'qry_2': ['strawberry'], 'qry_3': ['event.pear', 'apple.apple', 'strawberry']}
```

Notes:

1. This currently only searches for identifiers after `from`/`join` keywords. To search for field names chosen just after the `select` keyword, use `list(get_fields(i.tokens[-1], True))`.
2. `get_fields` will also `yield` subquery/table alias i.e if `apple.apple a` exists then `a` will also be yielded, along with `apple.apple`. If you don't want this behavior, just comment out `yield i.get_alias()`.

Comment: this works for the example above, but not able to run on my query string...i have identified the subqueries using ```r'' '(.+?) (?i)as \('``` but replacing that in ```re.split``` also produces error

Comment: @paranormaldist can you post your full query string?

Comment: I see why it was causing error, just need to add ```(?i)``` for case sensitive! @Ajax1234, such a great help with regex

Comment: if I wanted to have the reverse, so ```{qry_1' : ['apple']}```, etc could we do that?

Comment: @paranormaldist do you mean input with each individual sub query, like `['qry_1 as ( select some code, var as var_1 from apple where code.. and code..', 'qry_2 as ( select some code, where var as var_2 from pear where code.. and code..', 'qry_3 as ( select some code from strawberry join some code, from apple where var as var_3, )']`?

Comment: @paranormaldist please see my recent edit.

Comment: got it, excellent. it does pickup some noise - if i could search just for what exists in ```sub``` would I replace the ```re.split``` ?

Comment: @paranormaldist Yes, you would just iterate over your list of subqueries i.e `for i in subs`

Comment: and where would ```qry``` be within the syntax after creating ```for i in sub:```?

Comment: never mind I see :) replace ```i``` with ```qry```

Comment: actually, that's not quite working as expected ... i get ```{'qry_1': ['apple', 'qry_2', 'pear', 'qry_3', 'strawberry', 'apple']}``` as output with ```for i in sub:
    a, *b = re.findall('\w+(?=\sas\s\()|(?<=from\s)\w+', qry)```

Comment: @paranormaldist Can you post `sub`?

Comment: yes ```sub = ['apple','pear','strawberry']```

Comment: @paranormaldist My apologies, I understand the issue now. Please see my recent edit, as the code now filters the results from the `re.findall` to only include fields in `sub`

Comment: thank you! and i think one last question, i think I need the ```space ),``` comma part of this in ```re.findall``` how is that added to the syntax? - i'm having an issue of the sub being cut off in the search so searching for ```apple``` where ```appl``` exists in string search

Comment: @paranormaldist is the `space ),` to be included with the subquery name?

Comment: yea I need the pattern to match between ```as (``` and  ``` ),```

Comment: so something like ```re.findall('\w+(?=\s(?i)as\s\()|(?<=(?i)\s\),\w+', i)```

Comment: @paranormaldist I am a confused. The goal of the `re.findall('<expression>', i)` is to take in the subquery fragment and produce its name, along with the fields. The `re.split` in my code splits the full query on the `space ),` so that an additional `re.findall` is not necessary to pull the subquery statement between `as (` and ` ),`.

Comment: @paranormaldist If you do the `re.split`, you should not need to search between `as (` and `space ),`

Comment: apologies, I do know why now - because my actual ```sub``` includes ```.``` so it's cutting off and then unable to search for that value. for example ```apple.source``` becomes ```apple``` when i need to search for ```apple.source```

Comment: @paranormaldist I think the best approach is to use a sql parser. I will add a solution utilizing that shortly

Comment: @paranormaldist Please see my recent edit

Comment: this is is excellent thank you, I was not aware of ```sqlparse```