# Python regex search for lines starting with certain characters within substrings

Tags: python, regex, substring, findall

I'd like to use regex to search for lines starting with certain characters within substrings. I have a SQL string -

```
qry = ''' 
with 
qry_1 as ( -- some text
   SELECT ID, 
          NAME
   FROM   ( ... other code...
),
qry_2 as ( 
    SELECT coalesce (table1.ID, table2.ID) as ID,
           NAME
   FROM (...other code...
),
qry_3 as (
-- some text
     SELECT id.WEATHER AS WEATHER_MORN,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id.SUN
                ORDER BY id.TIME) AS SUN_TIME,
            id.RAIN,
            id.MIST
   FROM (...other code..
-- some other text
)
'''
```

I'm able to extract subquery information through `re.findall` here -

```
sub = re.findall(r'' '(.+?) (?i)as \(',qry)
```

Where `sub` output is `qry_1, qry_2, qry_3`
And I'd like to be able to extract any lines starting with this character `--` within those identified in `sub`. Something like this works for string values that I got help with [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66694363/regex-find-list-values-within-multiple-multi-line-strings-python)-

```
# search substring between strings 
params = [re.findall('^\w+|(?:--)|(?<=\.)(?:--)', i) 
     for i in re.findall('\w+\s(?i)as\s\([\s\w\.,\n]+', qry)]
dict_result = {a:None if not b else b for a, *b in params}

dict_result = dict([(k,dict_result[k]) for k in sub])
dict_result
```

But how to incorporate the `starts with` special character `--`? So the output is like this -

```
{'qry_1' : 'some text', 'qry_2': 'None', 'qry_3': 'some text, some other text'}
```

Thank you for guidance here

Answer (score 0):

For the example data, one option could be using a capture group for all the parts before  `as (` in group 1, and capture all lines after it in group 2 that do not contain  `as (`.

```
^(.+?) as \((.*(?:\n(?!.* as \().*)*)\n\)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(.+?)` Capture **group 1**
- `as \(` Match `as (`
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `.*` Match the rest of the line
  - `(?:\n(?!.* as \().*)*`
- `)` Close group 1
- `\n\)` Match a newline and `)`

Then you could use group 1 as the key of the dict, and use re.findall using the value of group 2 to find the strings that start with `--`  and capture what follows that again in a capture group, which will be returned by re.findall.

```
import re

regex = r"^(.+?) as \((.*(?:\n(?!.* as \().*)*)\n\)"
dict_result = {}
s = "the example string here"

for tup in re.findall(regex, s, re.MULTILINE):
    matches = re.findall(r"-- (.*)", tup[1])
    dict_result[tup[0]] = matches if len(matches) > 0 else None

print(dict_result)
```

Output

```
{'qry_1': ['some text'], 'qry_2': None, 'qry_3': ['some text', 'some other text']}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EmcC27/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/BwQN9i)